# Delete from multiple tables in one single query

Tags: sql, db2

I am a beginner in DB2. I want to delete from 2 tables using one query. The reason why I want to do that is because the condition for delete is complex and implies `JOIN` in big tables. I don't want to do the same query twice. Basically I want something like that :

```
DELETE from table1 t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID 
AND ID in ( -- some select and JOIN stuff)
```

Comment: Put the results of your complex query into a temporary table, then use that to delete from each of your target tables.  Probably within a single transaction.

Answer (score 3):

With DB2 for LUW you can do something like this using the *data change table reference*:

```
WITH lst (id) as ( -- some select and JOIN stuff),
lst1 (id) as (
  SELECT id FROM OLD TABLE (
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM lst)
  )
)
SELECT id FROM OLD TABLE (
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM lst1)
)
```

`OLD TABLE (DELETE ...)` is the data change table reference, which contains in this case all rows that have been deleted by the enclosed `DELETE`.

I don't think this trick is supported on other DB2 platforms, althought it might be in DB2 for z/OS v.11 -- I have no way of testing that though.

Comment: DB2 for i supports data change table reference (DCTR) since v6.1, but only `FINAL TABLE` and `NEW TABLE`.  But cool trick for LUW.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cant do that

My thoughts

- Running the same query twice should't be much issues specially because db usually get some cache.
- If the problem is performance maybe the problem is on the query, the server cpu or the disk.

Possible solution

- Create a trigger on table1 `on delete` where you will also delete same item on table 2