# in db2 , how to delete records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, db2

i've been trying many of the solutions found by googling, but none work with this seemingly simple task.

in db2, i want to delete PO and PO lines, based on PO vendor and PO date.

PO and PO lines are linked by PO number. (below don't work)

```
DELETE FROM po, po_lines 
  WHERE po_lines.po_num = po.po_num
  AND po.vendor = 'AAA' AND po.order_date = CURRENT DATE
```

TIA!

Comment: I'm don't think it is possible to delete from 2 tables in a single `delete command`. May be you can create a `stored procedure` with the 2 delete statements and call the stored procedure once.

Comment: ah really? thank you for raising that maybe indeed how i'm trying to do it is not really achievable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete from multiple tables in one single query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099521/delete-from-multiple-tables-in-one-single-query)

Answer (score 0):

The Delete statement only supports deleting rows from a single table. You can accomplish the same in 2 statements:

```
DELETE FROM po_lines WHERE po_num IN
(
   SELECT po.po_num FROM po_lines 
   JOIN po ON po_lines.po_num=po.po_num
   WHERE po.vendor = 'AAA' AND po.order_date = CURRENT DATE
);

DELETE FROM po WHERE po.vendor = 'AAA' AND po.order_date = CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: what happens if po_lines were deleted, a system crash happened before deleting the po header. we'd have PO's with no lines?

Comment: To avoid an error due to a system crash, the statements should be issued as a single transaction, with a commit or rollback after as appropriate. In MSSQL this would be [set implicit_transactions on]

Comment: That's what commitment control is for...don't `COMMIT` till both deletes are done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think it is possible to delete from 2 tables in a single `DELETE` command. May be you can create a `stored procedure` with the 2 delete statements and call the stored procedure once.

Answer (score 0):

not necessary join, and you must use 2 query

```
DELETE FROM po_lines pol 
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM po
   WHERE pol.po_num=po.po_num AND po.vendor = 'AAA' AND po.order_date = CURRENT DATE
);

DELETE FROM po WHERE po.vendor = 'AAA' AND po.order_date = CURRENT DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can delete rows from first table and then delete rows from second table, where associated column value not exists in first table no more:

```
delete from secondtable dt where not exists (select 1 from secondtable st where st.id = dt.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a with statement to create a temporary table with the I'd of the row/foreign keys you want to delete.

See https://pw999.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/delete-from-multiple-tables-in-db2-in-a-single-query/ for an exemple.
(Second result of Google after the link pointing here)